# How to determine whether a Joda DateTimeFormatter is 12-hour or 24-hour?

Tags: java, datetime, time, format, jodatime

For any given Joda [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instance, how can I programmatically determine whether it parses/formats times in 12-hour or 24-hour format?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ...
boolean is24HourFormat = ?
```

Comment: If you don't know how you have created the formatter then there is no way in Joda-API.

Comment: And what answer do you expect by pattern "HH:MM (hh:mm a)"? That pattern would be ambivalent.

Answer (score 1):

There is now API to do it in Joda library.
So you should use your own magic solution to do it.
E.g.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ...
boolean is24HourFormat = formatter
      .print(new DateTime(0L).withHourOfDay(13))
      .contains("13");
```